# jQuery image replace - help fixing code

Tags: jquery, css, image, replace

I have got a code to work on my website. I am currently using a text link with a href="#image1" anchor tag to replace an image within a specific div tag with another image.

The principle behind this, is when you click the text of an address, the map changes to an image of the map of that specific address.
However, I currently use a gradient overlay on the image and the actual map is coded in using css background image.

```
.map-grad {
    background-image: url(../img/map.png);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src=//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/local/map_gradient.png, sizingMethod=scale)";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map.png);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map.png);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map.png);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map.png);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map.png);
    background-position: center;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 1600px;
}
```

My jQuery is:

```
 var itemInfo = { // Initialise the item information
      img1: ['/img/map.png', ''],
      img2: ['/img/map2.jpg', ''],
};

$(function() {
      $('#maps a').click(function() { // When an item is selected
            var id = $(this).attr('href').replace(/#/, ''); // Retrieve its ID
            $('#info img').attr('src', itemInfo[id][0]); // Set the image
            $('#info p').text(itemInfo[id][1]); // And text
            return false; // Prevent default behaviour
      });
});
```

The image links are in the format of:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

and the actual image that is being replaced is as follows:

```
<div class="map-grad">
    <div id="info">
        <img src="/img/map.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me and suggest a way to replace these images through the css background image. A thought I had was to remove the background-image css tag from the .map-grad and simply put this as the following:

```
<div id="info">
<div class="map-grad" style="background-image: url(../img/map.png);"></div>
</div>
```

and code the jQuery to replace the css url rather than the img src it currently replaces?
Any thoughts and help?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `$('.map-grad').css('background-image', 'newMap.png');` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I need a way to replace all of the ../img/map.png links in the css.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to replace all the images, the only way i can think of is this

```
$.each($('*'), function( index, element ) {
   var element = $(element);
   if(element.css('background-image') === 'YourMap.png') {
      element.css('background-image', 'newMap.png');
   }
});
```

though it would be better to use a class or something instead of *

edit: if you have a class on all of your images you just do this

```
$('.myClass').css('background-image', 'newImg.png')
```

Comment: A CLASS!! Can't believe I didn't think of that. I can create a new class for each image. How can I use jQuery to alter the class of the div tag with relevance to my code above? That is something I am not sure on how to do..